# Photoshop knockout text to background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to make the overlapping part of the H white or transparent to the background how can i achieve this?

i have searched online but couldnt find a good solution.

I wanna do this with another image on the same block later aswell. would this work the same?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Could not understand your last sentence well, have to guess... but the rest and your example image is easy to achieve.
[image]

Steps:

1, a white background layer.

2, a text layer.

3, ctrl+j to copy/clone the text layer, change text to white or what ever.

4, in between the two text layers, insert your shape layer or what ever.

5, make the very top text "copy" layer a clipping mask (select that layer then CTRL+ALT+G)

All done. Select your shape layer, feel free to move your shape(or what ever) around.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to use Knockout layer blending. It's a bit nerdy, but bear with me.

1. So I have two layers and a bg:

[image]

2. I make a copy of them and set `Fill` to `0`:

[image]

3. Then I put them to groups with copy layers on top:

[image]

4. Then double click on each `Copy` layer and set `Knockout` to `Shallow` so the knockout effect will only work inside a group:

[image]

5. Knockout layers mask everything that's beneath them, so in `TRIANGLE` group `H copy` cuts `triangle` and in `H` `triangle copy` cuts the `h` layer. Result:

[image]

As a bonus: if you link knockout layers with their originals you can transform both knockouts and layers in the same time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select the Layers and create a duplicate]

[image: Move the text layer below the shape layer]

[image: Create a mask.]

[image: Change the color of the layer]

Select the Layers and create a duplicate
Move the text layer below the shape layer
Create a mask.
Change the color of the layer